# How to change dataset values and pass it to a pivot

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, pivot

I have a Dataset with a TableAdapter and when i say something like this

```
this.medicineDatasetTableAdapter.Fill(this.statisticsDataset.MedicineDataset);
```

It brings me all the results from a database and i show them using a pivot from DevExpress control.
I am using sqlite as database and i store in a filed datetime eg '1/4/2012' as string and when is the time to be show from the pivot with a grouping as DateMonth or whatever.. nothing is show up. I think that the pivot doesnt understand the format to group the dates..
Now i try to get the DataTable from the DataSet with the GetData command and change the datetime to a correct date and fill it again with the correct dates results.
One way i tryied is like

```
StatisticsDataset.MedicineDatasetDataTable datatable = this.medicineDatasetTableAdapter.GetData();

DataTable a = this.medicineDatasetTableAdapter.GetData();

foreach (DataRow row in a.Rows)
{
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.ItemArray[4].ToString(), Resources.ShortDateFormat, new CultureInfo(Resources.CurrentCulture));
                row[4] = tempDate;
            }
            this.statisticsDataset.MedicineDataset = a;
            //this.medicineDatasetTableAdapter.Fill(this.statisticsDataset.MedicineDataset);
            this.medicineDatasetTableAdapter.Fill((MedExpress.Dataset.StatisticsDataset.MedicineDatasetDataTable)a);
```

But it doesnt works. Any suggestions please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly seems to be a type issue.

Looking at the code you're taking a data from a 'Text' cell, converting it into a DateTime and then copying the value back into the same 'Text' cell (which would cast the value back into a string!).  I would suggest either...

- Create a new strongly typed DateTime cell for your MedicineDatasetDataTable and copy the parsed value into that cell.
- Why bother storing DateTime values as string, virtually all database products (sorry I've never used SQLLite) support this datatype and in a strongly typed scenario, there's no need to convert values.

Comment: Sorry i was late replaying to your comment.. i will try to change the type of the cell to DateTime and i will inform you for the result. But i think i already do that